# Wordpress loop to display posts in a table

Tags: wordpress-theming, html-table, wordpress

I know how to work with wordpress loops, but not sure how to create the logic necessary to display my loop in a table.

I want to display each post in a table cell, but then every 4th post create a new row so my table has 4 columns, and as many rows as needed.

Advice?

Comment: Please make a review for answer...

Answer (score 0):

As a example:--
You can do something like this...

```
<table>
<?php $i = 0;?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php if($i == 0){ echo "<tr>"; }?>
        <td>//Your Data..</td>
    <?php $i++;?>
    <?php if($i == 4){ echo "</tr>"; $i=0;}?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php if($i < 4) echo '</tr>'; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: You would also have to think about the times when the post count isn't a power of 4. Something like `<?php endwhile; ?><?php if($i < 4) echo '</tr>'; ?>`